# How do I start the Development Web Server to execute the php Hello World example?

Tags: google-app-engine

With reference to the [PHP Hello World](http://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/devserver) example, I have a command prompt window open in Windows7 in which I have entered "google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=C:/php/php-cgi.exe C:/helloworld/".

The response I get is: 'google_appengine' is not recognized as an internal or external command
operable program or batch file.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using \ instead of / for the entire command line.

Comment: Your suggestion must be pretty close because now I'm at least getting an error message from the Python Interpreter!